# Parse.com: Copy one object to another class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

How do you move an object in a class to another class? (Javascript / Cloude code)

I'm making a turn based game.

I have 2 classes In Parse;

- `ActiveMatches`
- `EndedMatches`

After a match ends, I want to move the match from the **Active** to **Ended** table.

Comment: seems like you'd be better suited just by having a "matches" class and setting a field "isEnded" to true when the game is over.